# Why Data is not send on to next page

Tags: spring, jsp

**Home Page table data is not passing to view product page on click but Id is Showing..**

**Home.jsp**

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Photo Thumb</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Condition</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>   
                    <th>View Product</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="#" alt="image" /></td>
                <td>${product.productID}</td>   
                <td>${product.productName}</td>
                <td>${product.productCategory}</td>
                <td>${product.productDescription} USD</td>
                <td>${product.productPrice} USD</td>
                <td>${product.productCondition}</td>
                <td>${product.productStatus}</td>
                <td>${product.productUnitInStock}</td>
                <td>${product.productManufacturer}</td>  
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/view/${product.productID}"/>">Click</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

This is My Home page and data is showing in a table but not passing to next page.
**Home Page **
[image: Home.jsp Page]

**ViewProduct.jsp**

```
  <section id="product" class="page-section bg-dark text-white">
        <div class="container text-center">
        <h2 class="viewPro">View Product !</h2>
        <h3 style="color: yellow">Here is The Deatails of the Product!</h3>
       </div>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="#" alt="image" style ="width:100%; height: 350px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3 style="color: white">Product Name :${product.productName}</h3>
                <h5 style="color: white">Category:${product.productCategory}</h5>
                <h5 style="color: white">condition:${product.productCondition}</h5>
                <h5 style="color: white">price : ${product.productPrice} USD</h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

This is view Product page and it is showing null value .
**View Product Page**
[image: View Product Page]

This is home controller page where i click to move on next page view Product page. 
**homeController.java**

```
   @Controller
    public class homeController {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private proDaoInterface dao;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String home(Model model) {
    List<ProductModel> productList = dao.getProductList();
    model.addAttribute("productList", productList);
    return "home";
 }

     @RequestMapping("/view/{productID}")
     public String viewProduct(@PathVariable String productID, Model model) 
     throws IOException {
     ProductModel product = dao.getProductByID(productID);
     model.addAttribute(product);
     return "viewProduct";

  }
```

Comment: Hello
can you share the java part as well which comes in picture after clicking this ><a href="<c:url value="/view/${product.productID}"/>">Click</a><

Comment: yes i added my java part which you want if any other code you want please tell me.

Comment: normal it should work,
It is silly but do one thing actually two things. replace productID with productId an check the "product " before adding in model

 @RequestMapping("/view/{productId}")
     public String viewProduct(@PathVariable String productId, Model model)